# tensorflow: what's the difference between tf.nn.dropout and tf.layers.dropout

Tags: tensorflow

I'm quite confused about whether to use tf.nn.dropout or tf.layers.dropout.

many MNIST CNN examples seems to use tf.nn.droput, with keep_prop as one of params.

but how is it different with tf.layers.dropout? is the "rate" params in tf.layers.dropout similar to tf.nn.dropout?

Or generally speaking, is the difference between tf.nn.dropout and tf.layers.dropout applies to all other similar situations, like similar functions in tf.nn and tf.layers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A quick glance through 
[tensorflow/python/layers/core.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py) and [tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py)
reveals that `tf.layers.dropout` is a wrapper for `tf.nn.dropout`.

The only differences in the two functions are:

1. The `tf.nn.dropout` has parameter `keep_prob`: "Probability that each element is kept"
    `tf.layers.dropout` has parameter `rate`: "The dropout rate"
    Thus, `keep_prob = 1 - rate` as defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L256)
2. The `tf.layers.dropout` has `training` parameter: "Whether to return the output in training mode (apply dropout) or in inference mode (return the input untouched)."

Comment: Thank You for your answer. oh i see. So can i generalize this case and say, for similar functions that found in tf.layers and tf.nn, the one in layers will mostly likely be a wrapper for the other one in tf.nn ?

Comment: @ntuty You are right! tf.layers is a higher-level wrapper, and tf.nn.dropout is from TensorFlow's low-level library. tf.nn.dropout is there since the first public release of TensorFlow (version 0.6?), while tf.layers.dropout is there since about version 1.0 or so.
As far as I know, the community develops new cool stuff in tf.contrib, which interfaces are likely to change. After a while, these are then transfered to tf.layers as soon as the interfaces (params, param-names, etc) are stable.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is the same, the parameters are slightly different. In [nn.dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout), *keep_prob is the probability that each element is kept*. In [layers.dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout) *rate=0.1 would drop out 10% of input units*.

So `keep_prob = 1 - rate`. Also layers.dropout allows `training` parameter.

In general, just read carefully documentation about the functions you care about and you will see the differences.

Comment: Thank you Salvador as well for your timely reply. :)

Answer (score 3):

On the training phase they are identical (as long as "drop rate" and "keep rate" are consistent). However, for evaluation (test) phase they are completely different. `tf.nn.dropout` will still do random dropping while `tf.layers.dropout` won't drop anything (transparent layer). In most cases it make sense to use `tf.layers.dropout`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answers from @nikpod and @Salvador Dali

The tf.nn.dropout scaled the weights by 1./keep prob during training phase, while tf.layers.dropout scaled the weights by 1./(1-rate).

During evaluation, You could set the keep prob to 1 which is equivalent to set training to false.